# npm async module not executing final callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am using the following code to output each item in an array. I see each individual log of the ('*****')...

But when the iteration is all complete, I don't see the 'iterating done' part.

```
async.forEach(stringsArray,function (item,callback) 
{
    //do something with the item
    console.log("*****");
},
function()
{
    //This function is called when the whole forEach loop is over
    console.log("Iterating complete");
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not executing the callback, so `async` doesn't know that you're done. Try this:

```
async.forEach(stringsArray, function(item, callback) { 
  console.log('*****');
  callback();
}, function() {
  console.log('iterating done');
});
```

Comment: You solved it! Thanks! I will mark as best answer as soon as StackOverflow lets me, says I have to wait 11 more minutes?